# FB.getLoginStatus doesn't fire if the user is not logged in to Facebook

Tags: javascript, oauth, facebook, oauth-2.0

I am working on a Facebook application which is integrated with Facebook and am trying to get the user's FB session. As far as I understand, a common usage scenario is as follows.

1. call `FB.init()`
2. call `FB.getLoginStatus` giving it an appropriate callback.

I ran the following code (the application id).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    function init(){
        FB.init({
            appId  : '9999999999999',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
            channelUrl : 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/channel.html', // custom channel
            oauth  : true // enable OAuth
        });
        alert('going to call FB.getLoginStatus ');

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            alert('whoo hoo!!! getLoginStatus called the callback');
        });
    }
    init();
    //-->
</script>
```

If the user is already logged in to Facebook in the same browser session then everything works as expected - returning the populated `_response.authResponse_`. However, if the user is not logged in to Facebook the callback is not triggered at all. Checking the browsers network log, I see that Facebook returns the following response (request from `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`?).

> Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.

I checked this on Chrome and Firefox (Mac).

---

**Update**

I would like to thank everyone who responded.

[Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69697/ben)'s comment had the answer.

Thanks Ben - you saved me lots of frustration.

Comment: Is your app in Sandbox Mode?  If so there appears to be a bug that could cause this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19359

Comment: Are you using channelUrl as loopback, or is that just for sample?  I do not believe loopback will work for that function.

Comment: the use of channelUrl is explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/). apparently it should speeds up the load time and helps avoid a few problems. 
don't really care if it does anything while i develop, should help when i go live.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause is a recent [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19359) which only affects sandbox mode. I switched off sandbox mode, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I could kiss you! Thank you very much. I've spend ALL night trying and trying out stuff... I didn't understand what happened... Nice job Facebook. 6 months after, the problem still remains...

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing loading the event:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    alert('whoo hoo!!! getLoginStatus called the callback');
}, true);
```

It is stated in *[FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)*.

The event might be not fired in some situations.

Comment: Adding true to force the load fixed the no response issue for me!