# Facebook API: checking if user is logged in on connect

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, pageload

I have been trying to get my website to check if the user is logged in on page load but I have not been able to get it to work despite following API instructions, here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
                alert('hello');
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                        appId  : 'APP_ID',
                        status : true, 
                        cookie : true,
                        xfbml  : true,
                        oauth  : true
                    });

                    FB.getLoginStatus(function( response ) {
                       console.log(response);
                       alert('hello2');  
                    });

                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                       alert('hello2');
                    });

                    FB.Event.unsubscribe('auth.statusChange');
               };
               (function(d){
                   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
               }(document));
           </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

The alert is never even hit unless the user is logged in, if he is logged out, this alert or anything that would be inside that code block never triggers.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above remove the trailing comma (oauth: true,) // that might just be from copy/paste but want to eliminate any gotchas

For debugging, console logging is my preferred method but since you're not even seeing alerts, your situation is a little bit tricky.

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.statusChange", function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});

FB.Event.unsubscribe("auth.statusChange");
// If you were to get subscribe to work, think about unsubscribing at some point to, since most likely that's only for an initial check
```

Alternatively, try using the getLoginStatus instead of the event subscription.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function( response ) {
    console.log(response);  
});
```

Response should give you an object and you can check `response.status` and its possible values are: connected, not_authorized or unknown
`response.authResponse` will include properties like: accessToken, expiresIn, etc.

Comment: Sometimes the auth.statusChange event doesn't trigger and I think it's due to network latency or server timeouts. I've found that working with FB requires being flexible with page loads not "working" 100% of the time. A refresh might trigger the event correctly.

Comment: Okay, I just realized that it works ONLY IF the user is logged into facebook (with app authed or w/o app authed)

Is there anyway to check if the user is logged off or the status of a logged off user? I feel like the getLoginStatus should be checking if user is logged off but it isn't, only if they have authorized the application.
I took your suggestion of getLoginStatus but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: Hmm.. your response should return an object like this:  {authResponse: null,
status: "unknown"}

Comment: Hey @Ven can you post your entire test page? I'm curious if there's anything else going on with FB.init, maybe failing for some reason. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I have updated my post to provide the full code aside from my appID. There are no errors in the console

Comment: Found out it's a bug with sandbox mode, should've tried searching different keywords in stackOverflow. Here's the link to the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230324/fb-getloginstatus-doesnt-fire-if-the-user-is-not-logged-in-to-facebook